# looping through a script setting

Tags: bash, unix, for-loop, numbers

I have a script that takes in as one of its options a number from 0-1. I want to test what these different settings do so I want to loop through all of them. I want generated the numbers with this:

```
for ((i=0; i <= 10; i += 1)); do echo "scale=1; ${i}/10"| bc; done
```

However when I try this the `bc` doesn't evaluate the `scale=1; ${i}/10` before it is taken by setting and so I end up using `scale=1; ${i}/10` instead of the actual number I want:

```
for ((i=0; i <= 10; i += 1)); do Myscript --input testdata --setting "scale=1; ${i}/10"| bc; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to command-substitute `echo "scale=1; ${i}/10" | bc` if you want to include it as literal text:

```
 for ((i=0; i <= 10; i += 1)); do
   Myscript --input testdata --setting $(echo "scale=1; ${i}/10"| bc)
 done
```

However, it would be much easier to do the following:

```
 for i in 0 0.{1..9} 1; do
   Myscript --input testdata --setting $i
 done
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this loop:

```
for ((i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )); do
    Myscript --input testdata --setting "$(bc -l <<< "scale=1; ${i}/10")"
done
```